# How can I add serial number beginning from 141 after each hash sign?

Tags: text-processing

How can I programmatically change this text file

```
put returns between paragraphs#
20170218
for linebreak add 2 spaces at end# blah
_italic_ or **bold**#
20170219
20170220#
201702#21
```

into this using tools like sed?

```
put returns between paragraphs#141
20170218
for linebreak add 2 spaces at end#142 blah
_italic_ or **bold**#143
20170219
20170220#144
201702#14521
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's technically possible with sed (it's Turing complete), it's very hard, because sed doesn't have arithmetic. This is a job for awk.

If you only want to replace the first `#` on each line, just tell it to replace `#` by `#` followed by an increasing number. Awk automatically converts integers to their decimal notation in strings.

```
awk -v n=141 '/#/ {sub(/#/, "#" (++n))}'
```

If you want to replace each `#` character, the simplest way is to make `#` the field separator and add the number at the beginning of each field except the first:

```
awk -v n=141 -F '#' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i = (++n) $i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
< yourfile perl -slpe 's/#/$&.$k++/e' -- -k=141
```

can also be used to perform the edits.

Comment: It only changes the first `#` and doesn't repeat the process for rest of the `#`s. Do I need to install something additionally? I'm on a Mac and am using perl 5.16.0.

Comment: Maybe what's happening on Mac is Perl is not doing a line-split , i.e, to it the whole file is one record. You could try giving the `s///ge` option as I am not on Mac so cannot try at my end.